# What does it mean "to fetch" before I can push?

Tags: github

I uploaded my whole project on my repository of github yesterday.

I'd like to update the online version today, and when I use `git push -u origin master`order, the bash window says:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
```

So how do I "fetch"?

If I use `git pull` first, would my local files be overwritten by the online version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how do I "fetch"?

By using the command:

```
git fetch
```

Basically, your local repo is out of sync with the remote (Github) repository. If you have multiple remote repos, you can specify which one, and you can also specify which branch. Try

```
git help fetch
```

for a complete description of the command and the various parameters you can pass in.

> If I use git pull first, would my local files be overwritten by the online version?

`git pull` is like doing a `git fetch` followed by `git merge` -- that is, it gets the updates from the remote and attempts to merge those into your local files. That may be fine, or not, depending on what you intend. Read the help for both commands so that you can make an informed decision.